# Threads and Their interaction with a Concurrent Dictionary and sw.Flush();

Tags: c#, multithreading, networking, client, concurrentdictionary

Consider this code:

```
class program
{
    public static ConcurrentDictionary<string, int> dictionary = new ConcurrentDictionary<string,int>();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        runServer();
    }

    static void runServer()
    {
        //Server setup

        Handler threadRequest;  
        Thread[] threadsArray = new Thread[2];
        int i = 0;

        while(true)
        {
            Socket connection;
            connection = listener.AcceptSocket();

            threadRequest = new Hander();

            threadsArray[i] = new Thread(() => threadRequest.clientInteraction(connection, dictionary));

            threadsArray[i].Start();
            i++;
        }       

    }
}

class Handler
{
    public void clientInteraction(Socket connection, ConcurrentDictionary<string, int> dictionary)
    {
        NetworkStream socketStream;

        socketStream = new NetworkStream(connection);   

        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(socketStream);
                StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(socketStream);

        parseStrings(out pTeamName); //checks to see if its a valid "add team" request

        dictionary.tryAdd(pTeamName, 0);

        while(dictionary.Count < 2)
        {
            //hang until two teams
        }

        sw.WriteLine("Welcome To The Game.");
        sw.Flush();

        foreach(KeyValuePair<string, int> kvp in dictionary)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Team: {0}", kvp.Key);
                }



                foreach(KeyValuePair<string, int> kvp in dictionary)
                {
                    sw.WriteLine("Team: {0}", kvp.Key);
                    sw.Flush();
                }
    }


}
```

This program takes in two client connections as different threads and runs the `clientInteraction` method in the handler class for each thread. My worry is that if the two threads hit `sw.Flush()` at the same time, the server is unable to execute it.

I'm reasoning that this is the case as the server isn't printing "Welcome To The Game" to either client and is only printing one entry of `dictionary` (the same entry) to both the clients and omitting one.

From debugging and the `Console.WriteLine` to just the server console, I know the dictionary is populated correctly. I'm just confused as to why the writing to the clients isn't working.

Any help welcome and if I've omitted anything important then let me know. Thanks in advance.

EDIT: It seems that for whatever reason every 'other' set of flushes work. For example I have put:

```
 while(true)
 {
     sw.WriteLine("BOO");
     sw.Flush();
     Console.ReadKey();
  }
```

Just below the foreach loop to print the dictionary to the clients. The first two `ReadKeys` print "BOO" to one of the clients (depending which thread is first), then the next the two do nothing. The next two however print "BOO" again. I don't particularly want to frame every `sw.Flush()` with a i=2 `for` loop just to get it to work.

Comment: It appears you have an infinite loop in the `while(true)` loop because I don't see a `break` or `return`.

Comment: @Quantic It's a server; that's what you'd expect out of at least a primitive server.

Comment: @Servy Ok my bad. I guess the only problem then is that `threads[2]` doesn't exist so it will simply crash after `i++` runs a 2nd time. I'll see myself to the door as I don't have much useful input otherwise.

Comment: @Quantic Yes, you're right that this breaks after accepting the second connection.

Comment: If i only ever plans to have 2 connections, is this going to be a problem? Obviously it could be broken if I tried to connect again, but won't it just listen for a third connection that never comes while I do what I need to do in the clientInteraction method?

Comment: @James If you want the server to shut down after accepting the second connection, then shut down the server after accepting the second connection.

Answer (score 0):

It's not your responsibility to ensure that none of the separate connections ever perform an action at the same time.  You need to ensure that you don't use/access a *single* connection from multiple threads at the same time, but it's the operating system's responsibility to ensure that the actions of different connections don't affect each other.

Comment: OK well if I'm leaving all concurrency issues up to the OS I'm at a loss as to why my streamwriters aren't working.